# Where is the error on this query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am developing an application and it needs to setup all the tables on a mysql server.But I am having a problem with one table.This is the query:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emails (
      'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      'em_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
      'cuenta' varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      'link' text NOT NULL,
      'fecha' timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      'conf' int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      'confirmed' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      'used' int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      'used_time' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      PRIMARY KEY ('id','cuenta')
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And when my application runs it I got this:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'em_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'cuenta' v' at line 2
```

I am out of ideas,please help me.Thanks

Comment: Leave the quotes around id, em_id etc.

Comment: Single quotes are invalid for column names. Change them to backticks `\``.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get rid of the quotes around your column identifiers. Either use ticks or nothing at all:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emails (
      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      em_id int(11) NOT NULL,
      cuenta varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      link text NOT NULL,
      fecha timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      conf int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      confirmed timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      used int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      used_time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      PRIMARY KEY (id,cuenta)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emails (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `em_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cuenta` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `link` text NOT NULL,
  `fecha` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `conf` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `confirmed` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `used` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `used_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`cuenta`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Better ticks then fleas; or is that the other way around? ;-)

Comment: Lol. Never heard that one before. :)

Comment: *Me neither* lol Actually I made it up just now. Seems like I'm a better comedian than I am a coder lol

Comment: Well, at least you have a night job if you need one. ;)

Comment: Yeah, it's called "sleep" hahaha; cuz even that is work on its own. Hard to get a good night's sleep, in this day & age anyway!

Comment: Hallelujiah and Amen to that ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should use backticks instead of single quotes `'` :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emails (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `em_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cuenta` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `link` text NOT NULL,
  `fecha` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `conf` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `confirmed` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `used` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `used_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`cuenta`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

[**Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52b9b)

Comment: You missed a few quotes in the primary key definition